# How to say "vice versa" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

I'm translating this:

> Duplicate question and answer type selection is not allowed, i.e. the question
>   cannot contain the answer, and *vice versa*.

as:

> 同じ質問と回答のタイプを選ぶのは許可されていません。
>   すなわち、質問には答えを組み込むことは許可されるわけではありません。
>   その逆の場合にも、同じことだ。

From the English Cambridge dictionary, "vice versa" is defined as:

> used to say that what you have just said is also true in the opposite order

and I'm translating it as:

> その逆の場合にも、同じことだ。

or, alternatively:

> その逆も同じです。

I'm also using the more formal "すなわち" instead of "つまり", and translating this:

> 許可されるわけではありません

as

> I doesn't make sense to allow it

and I also realise that

> 組み込むことは許可されるわけではありません

sounds a bit too heavy. A Google search gives hits on "許可されるわけではない", but not on "ことは許可されるわけではない".

Comment: After reading your post, I'm not quite sure what you are asking for.

Comment: ah yes, the title question basically: how to properly say "vice versa", as used in the above sentence, and what a commonly used expression of it is in Japanese. Can also add that the above sentence is a bit formal, so I would like a similarly formal expression (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to translate *vice versa*, from rather casual その反対でも同じです to highly literary 逆もまた真なり, but in your case その逆も同様です should work.

回答のタイプを選ぶのは許可されていません means "you cannot select the type of an answer", which does not seem to fit the following context. If this "answer type selection" means "marking your post as an answer", say (投稿の)タイプを回答にする, タイプとして回答を選ぶ, (投稿)種別の選択欄を回答にする, 回答として投稿する, etc. 許可されていません can be actually too heavy depending on what you are explaining, so consider using simple ～はできません.

All in all, assuming this is a user-friendly doc of a kind of net forum, something like this should work:

> 同じ質問を投稿することや、投稿種別として回答を選ぶことはできません。つまり、質問が回答を含むことはできませんし、その逆も同様です。